# Return column names instead of table names in SQLite after join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have such query

```
SELECT "sq0"."_backward_relation_key","team"."name","team"."id" 
FROM "team" 
JOIN (SELECT "event_id" "_backward_relation_key","team_id" "_forward_relation_key" FROM "event_team" WHERE "event_id" IN (2)) 
"sq0" ON "sq0"."_forward_relation_key"="team"."id"
```

In postgres it returns column names in such way:

```
_backward_relation_key | name | id
```

But in sqlite it returns them in such fashion

```
sq0 | team | team
```

Is there any way to change sqlite behaviour to make it similar to postgres without changing query itself?

Comment: Can you also tell us where/how you are running your query?  The obvious workaround is to use aliases.

Comment: This query is generated in runtime by python and run into sqlite3 driver. I could use aliases, but the point is that this query can be generated for different table in runtime and want to keep it universal enough and aliases aren't working for it

Comment: This bug was fixed a long time ago. Update your SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - The *only* way you can guarantee that column names will be what you want in SQLite is to use aliases.